# Deleting a repo from git in my PC's folder without affecting the synchronized files at the other PCs

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitkraken

I am a totally noob in GIT. 
I cloned a repo from a project in Gitkraken, which is connected to GitLab.
My question is: 
If I delete the repo at my PC's folder, 
would it affect the repos at the others PC's? 
I am little feared that I can delete the whole project from the other computers.

Thank you very much if you can help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no, by deleting a local folder in the git repository you only delete it locally.

However, if you commit the changes and push them to the upstream repo on the server, the deleted files will only be accessible through older states of the git repository.

I recommend a good read of some git tutorials and how synchronization in git works.

Comment: Ohh now I get it! Thank you very very much!! you helped me a lot to improving my understanding for git

Comment: thank me by accepting the answer if that solved your problem. This will also mark this question as solved.